# Cannot resolves symbol packetInterceptor

Tags: android

I am trying to run the XMPP-based App Server based on [Smack library](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement)

I'v added the required dependencies based on smack 4.1.0. I have problem with one Import:

```
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
```

I experience the error message

> Cannot resolves symbol PacketInterceptor

How do I resolve this?

Comment: When it tells you "can not resolve", then the according dependencies are not correctly defined. It would help if you can post your gradle file (or whatever you use for defining dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle, use following dependencies

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.0.1"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.0.6"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.0.6"
```

Or download the jar for the smack 4.0.6

Apparently, in the latest 4.1.0-Beta version they made some change to API but lack of enough clear documents.